# How to subscribe to Redis events with C#

Tags: c#, redis, publish-subscribe

I have a remote computer which is uses Redis. I want to receive notifications about it Redis events (updates, new keys etc.). I've searched online for solution and landed on StackExchange.Redis, then i've started to create windows service that will listen to Redis events. I have found code example:

```
var endp = "x.x.x.x:xxxx"
using (ConnectionMultiplexer connection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(endp))
{
    IDatabase db = connection.GetDatabase();
    ISubscriber subscriber = connection.GetSubscriber();
    int f = 0;
    subscriber.Subscribe("__keyspace@0__:*", (channel, value) =>
        {
            if ((string) channel != null)
            {
                f++;
                // Do stuff if some item is added to a hypothethical "users" set in Redis
            }                     
        }
    );
}
```

for now i wan't to get all of it events and just increase counter. Is this enough or i've missed something?

Comment: not being familiar with this particular API, it almost appears as though you're entering your `while(true)` loop inside the delegate that's called when an event arrives - shouldn't your loop be in a different scope?

Comment: yeah, lets get rid of it for now

Comment: you right. Misspelled.

Comment: the code shown looks like it should work, except for the fact that you're going to be tearing down the connections when you exit the `using` block; you kinda need to leave the connections open if you want to catch anything; note that there is a secondary subscription API in 2.* if you need async work - essentially works like a `Channel<T>`

Comment: how to make this listener stay active for all service runtime.

Comment: @Fallingsappy just... don't kill it? rather than a `using` block, make the connection be a field on your service class, so that it lives for the same duration